# Как обработать двумерный массив json?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Друзья, ситуация такова:

С помощью AJAX я делаю запрос для выгрузки данных из БД.

```
 var obj;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/functions/dbfunctions.php",
    data: {
    type: 7,
    id: id,
    }
  }).done(function(msg){

    obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);

  });
```

Вот сам php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM multiplys WHERE sale = '$action'");
$data_multiplys = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo json_encode($data_multiplys);
```

Поскольку из БД выводится не одна строка, а не определенное количество, так как я не знаю сколько записей оно найдет то в результате я не знаю как создать уже на стороне обработки цикл, который бы мог пройтись по всем записям которые будут в полученой строке. Пожалуйста помогите создать цикл с которым я могу пропарсить возвращенный мне json с массивами

**ПРАВКИ**

Вот полный код запроса:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/functions/dbfunctions.php",
data: {
type: 7,
id: id,
}
```

}).done(function(msg){

```
ЗДЕСЬ НУЖНО ЦИКЛОМ ОБРАБОТАТЬ JSON
```

}

});

Вот сам PHP в том состоянии что сейчас есть

```
//load Multiply data
  if($_POST['type']==7)
  {
    $action = $_POST['id'];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM multiplys WHERE sale = '$action'"); // ЗДЕСЬ МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ 10 записей

    $data_multiplys = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    echo json_encode($data_multiplys);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример перебора двумерного JSON массива в цикле `for`

```js
var json_string = [
  {"name":"Will","age":"12"},
  {"name":"John","age":"29"}
];

for(var i in json_string) {
  alert(json_string[i].name + ', ' + json_string[i].age);
}
```

Comment: К сожалению не получилось. В своем вопросе я отредактировал код, что бы более наглядно было понятно что у меня есть. Я пробовал ваш вариант но он почему то не сработал. цикл безпрерырвно начал идти.

Comment: В данном случае ваш ответ более соответствует вопросу, поэтому отмечаю как правильный. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в запрос dataType: "JSON" и даже парсить ничего не придется:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/functions/dbfunctions.php",
  dataType: "JSON",
  success: function(data) {
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        console.log(data[i]);
    }
  }
});
```